# how to pass content of file variable in fish shell

Tags: shell, fish

I want to use the `.pem` for secure `ssh` connection so how can I pass the content of the pem to a variable in fish script?

```
set key /Users/mesutgunes/project/mproject-key.pem
ssh -i (cat $key) labs[1] ???
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set environment value.

```
set file /Users/mesutgunes/project/mproject-key.pem
ssh -i $file host
```

regards

Comment: it gives an error **Warning: Identity file `cat not accessible: No such file or directory.**

Comment: I think you meant `ssh -i $key $labs[1]`. it is not depending on variable name. Thaks

Comment: Yes, you are correct. It should suffice with just the parameter -i.